# Python3: string to variable

Tags: python, string, variables, python-3.x

I've looked everywhere for this but haven't found a suitable answer yet and I don't want to use a dictionary.

How can I convert a string to a variable name? For example I have this call:

```
object.variable
```

This `variable` is defined in the `object`. However I have a LOT of variables (for a reason) and more to come. It seems stupid to do this:

```
s = 'variable'
if s == 'variable': object.variable
elif s == 'variable2: object.variable2
etc....
```

So is there a way to convert a string to a variable name?

Comment: Have you considered using a `dict`?

Comment: I implicitly stated I don't want to use a dictionary, so yes I have considered it but don't think it's the best solution.

Comment: @Tim: Just an aside; if you find running into this problem, you are probably doing something wrong in the design of the code. While it is possible, it is extremely unlikely that your use case is a unique one in which `gettattr()` access to attributes is a good solution.

Comment: @JoelCornett, to be honest, I'm a good programmer but certainly not the best so the possibility of doing something wrong in the design is most definitely an option. However, I've no idea how to do it differently.

Comment: Could you use `object[s]`? (Or do  you already use `__getitem__` for something else?)

Answer (score 1):

```
getattr(object, variable)
```

However I don't see any good reason to be accessing attributes like this...

Comment: Well, it's just a program I use for my thesis so know one will ever use it again. Each attribute has different information stored about the object and I want to use them all to compare in machine learning.